# Why is this decibels calculation /10 instead of /20?

Tags: decibel, audiokit

AudioKit supports normalizing an audio file to a given max level in decibels (dB).

My understanding is that these would be field quantities not power quantities.

Thus, shouldn't this be `/ 20.0` instead of `/ 10.0`?

```
let gainFactor = Float( pow(10.0, newMaxLevel / 10.0) / pow(10.0, level / 10.0))
```

and shouldn't this be `20 *` instead of `10 *`?

```
return 10 * log10(maxLev)
```

Code in question:

https://github.com/AudioKit/AudioKit/blob/9ae8641551bc5f7b4c9b4c887aa327155fac83b5/AudioKit/Common/Internals/Audio%20File/AKAudioFile%2BProcessing.swift#L42

https://github.com/AudioKit/AudioKit/blob/9ae8641551bc5f7b4c9b4c887aa327155fac83b5/AudioKit/Common/Internals/Audio%20File/AKAudioFile.swift#L294

Reference:

http://www.sengpielaudio.com/calculator-db.htm

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field,_power,_and_root-power_quantities

Thanks!

Comment: Hint: What does "deci" in "decibel" stand for?

Comment: This is also in dire need of code you're trying to get working to keep it on-topic. Off-site links are problematic.

Comment: Looking at your reference, `dBu` and `dB` are two different beasts; it's the second you want.

Comment: Code added and it's referencing permalinks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common misunderstanding among electrical engineering students when learning about power gain and voltage/current gain on a log scale, I'm surprised you've encountered it here.

In my field log scale graphs are used most often to represent the power gain of a system over a given frequency range. In this case a 10 db rise in power corresponds with a 10 fold increase in power. However the same isn't true for voltages and currents; if a signal's voltage or current increases 10 fold then the signal's increase in power will *not* be 10 fold, it will be sqrt(10) ~= 3.16. This is because power increases proportionally with the *square* of voltage and current.

Thus when we take the log of an equation for a signal's power over frequency we will find something like this; (for a resistor)

```
log(P(ω)) = log(V(ω)^2 / R) = 2log(V(ω)) - log(R)
```

Multiply both sides by 10 to convert Bels to Decibels;

```
10log(P(ω)) = 20log(V(ω)) - 10log(R)
```

The relationship between the amplitude and power of a sound wave is similar to the relationship between the amplitude and power of an electrical signal AFAIK. This is why a 20 db increase in amplitude corresponds to a 10 fold increase in amplitude and a 10 db increase in power corresponds to a 10 fold increase in power.

P.S. To answer your question you need to determine if the levels are a unit of power or a unit of amplitude. You know more about the units the function uses than I do as my experience with audio files is highly limited, but my instinct is that an audio file is a representation of amplitude, in which case you would be correct; the conversion factors would need to be 20, not 10.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure this answers the actual question though.

Comment: I edited my answer, but I've given you an explanation of why it would be 10 vs. 20 and you know more about the units the library uses than I do, I can't connect the dots for you

Comment: Great, I agree.

Comment: I created a pull request to fix AudioKit this way.

Comment: @BrianH I don't see a pull request on the AudioKit repo, are you sure you created the pull request correctly?